# How would you store results of a for-loop as a single array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I've managed to create a for-loop, which provides me with the results that I want, but I'm struggling to collate these results into a single array, so that I can plot it as my x value on a graph.

I have considered collating them into a single list first (but am also struggling to do this).

I have also tried to append, extend, and stack the array below, but nothing seems to work.

When trying to append, I got an error message appears to say that there is not 'value' present.

```
a = 0.1
x = 0.2 

for i in range(1,10):  
    a = a**3
    x = x**2
    array = np.array ([a, x])

    print (array)
```

The code above provides 9 individual arrays, as opposed to just 1.

i.e. `[(a1, x1), (a2, x2), ... (a9, x9)]`

Any suggestions to fix this or alternative methods would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: show us your code so wee can help you :)

Comment: Hi, sorry, just realised it didn't upload right. oops

Comment: You are re-defining the array within your loop. Define it **one** time, **outside** your loop - and add items to it iteratively inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

okk  so you want to store both variable values in this pattern (a1,x1),(a2,x2)....

So this can be done in this way 
like first suppose two separate `list` for a and x , and then `merge` them into the desired format

the whole code is shown here

```
import numpy as np
a = 0.1
x = 0.2 
list1= []
list2=[]
for i in range(1,10):  
    a = a**3
    x = x**2
    list1.append(a)
    list2.append(x)
merged_list = [(list1[i], list2[i]) for i in range(0, len(list1))]
print(merged_list)
```

this will give you the desired output . Thanks for asking

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You can use `zip` here in list comprehension. `[(i,j) for i ,j in zip(list1, list2)]`

Comment: Yes  zip will also work fine but since this is the basic error , so i thought that , may be he is just started with Python . so make it more simpler

Answer (score 2):

Use `append` to append value in `list`

```
a = 0.1
x = 0.2 

array = []
for i in range(1,10):  
    a = a**3
    x = x**2
    array.append([a, x])

print(array)
```

**If you want numpy.array**

```
a = np.power(np.repeat(0.1, 10), 3)
x = np.power(np.repeat(0.2, 10), 2)

print(np.array(list(zip(a,x))))
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: @TrebledJ Output provided by OP looks more like a `list` than `array`

Comment: If I wanted it to be an array, would I just have to use np.array?

Comment: @TrebledJ added solution for `numpy.arrays`

Comment: thank you!! Is there a way to do that for more complicated equations?

Comment: @pinkbonsai depends on your equation, explore `numpy` library.

Comment: I've just tried to np.array my previous list (without zipping it), and have lots of values that say list[(a1, x1)], list [(a2, x2)] etc

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to **append multiple items to a list**?

First solution:

```
l = []
for i in range(1,10):
    a = a**3
    x = x**2
    l.extend([a, x])
print(l)
```

Second solution:

```
l = []
for i in range(1,10):
    a = a**3
    x = x**2
    l+= [a, x]
print(l)
```

Do you want to **append multiple items to a numpy array**?

```
array = np.array([])
for i in range(1,10):
    a = a**3
    x = x**2
    array = np.append(array, [a,x])
print(array)
```

Comment: array != list :)